# How to output 'is null' in a where clause in a case when statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

The query checks the value of a parameter **foo** which is passed by a dropdown inside a program. If that paramater contains a certain value, an attribute should only contain null values. Can I manage that without pl/SQL?

```
select * from table t
where case when $foo$ = 'yes' then t.something is null end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this logic?

```
select something 
from table t
where ($foo$ = 'yes' and t.something is null) or ($foo != 'yes')
```

Comment: Yes, sir. Thank you, may Jesus bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `nvl` function :

```
select * 
  from mytable t
 where nvl($foo$,'yes') = 'yes';
```